# Keyboard shown only after second attempt

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

In my app after some event i want my user to fill `EditText`. In order to do that, i request focus on this `EditText` and try to show keyboard using this code:

```
public void onGivenEvent(int which) {
  mMyDialog.dismiss(getActivity());
  mMyEditField.requestFocus();
  InputMethodManager imm =
      (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.showSoftInput(mMyEditField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

xml for `mMyEditField` looks like this:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edit_field"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:background="@null"
  android:digits="0123456789.,"
  android:freezesText="true"
  android:hint="some hint"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone"
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
  android:maxLength="15"
  android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"
  android:textSize="16sp" />
```

The funny thing is, this code doesn't show keyboard on first attempt. When this code is executed once, after device rotation keyboard is shown properly. I had similiar problem with `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`not working correctly, but i used workaround - I set `OnFocusChangeListener` with `mMyEditField.selectAll()` inside.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: means are you show your keyboard after user enter a value in edittext?

Comment: I have some Dialog and after user perform click "ok" on this dialog "onGivenEven" is called and i want to show keyboard for my EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Call This method from your onGivenEvent() function**

```
public void showSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am kinda confused, but `toggleSoftInputFromWindow` works perfectly while `showSoftInput` does nothing. Nevertheless, my problem is solved.